# Skip syslog/rsyslog logging of certain cron jobs

Tags: linux, debian, cron, syslog

In most GNU/Linux distributions the default is to log start (and many different events) of every cron job to syslog. It's rather convenient, but not for a very frequent jobs, which started, say, every 1 minute.

I know how to redirect all cron jobs events to a different log via `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (`*.*;cron,auth,authpriv.none -/var/log/syslog`) and it's easy to heavily restrict the logging to, say, just error events via `/etc/default/cron` (`EXTRA_OPTS="-L 4"`). But this affect all of cron jobs.

What if I want to restrict the logging of *certain* cron jobs (said frequent every-1-minute jobs)? Is it possible to set this up via `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or in `/etc/crontab` itself? The system is Debian 8.0 Jessie.

Comment: From a 50+ year career in computing, the last half in security, I see suppression of logs as a major No-No.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO not possible via config files because that, as you say, would affect **all** cron jobs for the user.

However it's possible to forcefully redirect just the stdout output or both stdout and stderr of specific cron jobs like this:

```
* * * * * cron_cmdline_job1 >> /<path>/cron_job1.stdout.log
* * * * * cron_cmdline_job2 >>& /<path>/cron_job2.stdout_stderr.log
```

The advantage of redirecting just stdout would be that you'd immediately get and email with the stderr content when the job ends (if that's your preference, can equally well be seen as a disadvantage).

If such logs are of no interest then you can direct to **/dev/null** instead, of course.

Comment: The question is not how to redirect output of cron jobs, but how to disable the cron service from logging that these cron jobs has been started. This is annoying for every-minute jobs.

Comment: I see. I don't think you can since there is no logging-related env var or other knob that you can selectively apply to individual job entries inside the crontab file.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single, long-running `cron` job that does the every 1 minute jobs? Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
flagfile="/var/run/longrunner.pid"
rm -f "$flagfile" 2>/dev/null
printf "$PID\n" >"$flagfile"
while [[ -e "$flagfile ]] ; do
    shortjob &
    sleep 60s
done
```

I put `shortjob` in the background so it doesn't distort the 60 second sleep. Since `sleep` isn't limited to integer values, you can tune the delay.

You can stop the "every minute" job submission by `kill -9 $(cat /var/run/longrunner.pid)` OR `rm /var/run/longrunner.pid`.